# Add java doc keymap to netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7.2

I'd like to setup a key map to generate the structure of a java doc in Netbeans 7.2. I'm wondering if anybody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There is already a Key Map set up to do this called "Generate Javadoc". If you go to the tools menu, then options and select keymap you can search for "Generate Javadoc" in the search box and set it to the key map of your choosing.